# Type constraints are ending up ambiguous

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

In a Haskell app I'm working on, I have an API in which I'm trying to set up a pluggable set of backends. I'll have several different backend types and I want the caller (right now, just the test suite) to determine the actual backends. However, I'm getting an ambiguous type error.

```
class HasJobQueue ctx queue where
    hasJobQueue :: JobQueue queue => ctx -> queue

class JobQueue q where
    enqueue :: MonadIO m => Command -> q -> m ()

type CloisterM ctx queue exc m = ( Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadError exc m, MonadReader ctx m
                                 , AsCloisterExc exc
                                 , HasJobQueue ctx queue
                                 , JobQueue queue
                                 )

createDocument :: forall ctx queue exc m. CloisterM ctx queue exc m => Path -> Document -> m DocumentAddr
createDocument path document = do
    ...
    queue   <- hasJobQueue <$> ask
    enqueue (SaveDocument addr document) queue
    ...
```

So, to me this seems pretty clear. In `createDocument`, I'm wanting to retrieve the context, and from that retrieve the job queue, which the caller would define and attach to the context. But Haskell disagrees and gives me this error:

```
• Could not deduce (JobQueue q0)
    arising from a use of ‘hasJobQueue’
  from the context: CloisterM ctx queue exc m
    bound by the type signature for:
               createDocument :: CloisterM ctx queue exc m =>
                                 Path -> Document -> m DocumentAddr
    at src/LuminescentDreams/CloisterDB.hs:32:1-105
  The type variable ‘q0’ is ambiguous
• In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘hasJobQueue’
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to build, this one from my API test suite where I am mocking all of the backends with simple IORefs, where production will have other backend implementations

```
data    MemoryCloister  = MemoryCloister WorkBuffer
newtype WorkBuffer      = WorkBuffer (IORef [WorkItem Command]) 

instance JobQueue WorkBuffer where 
    hasJobQueue (MemoryCloister wb) = wb

instance JobQueue WorkBuffer where
    ...
```

So, what exactly do I need to do to help the type checker understand that the context in the `MonadReader` contains an object that implements the `JobQueue` class?

---

The entire data types file, including how I ultimately reformulated the JobQueue for something more flexible than even the above, is [in this project](https://github.com/savannidgerinel/cloisterdb/blob/sol/src/LuminescentDreams/CloisterDB/Types.hs)

Comment: I’m not entirely sure if this is okay, depending on your particular problem, but you are likely able to add a functional dependency to `HasJobQueue`, making it `class HasJobQueue ctx queue | ctx -> queue`, which I think would fix this issue.

Comment: I think the functional dependency proposed by @AlexisKing is _the_ way to go. To be clear, it would be asserting that any context has only one queue (so that GHC can now be sure that specifying just the `ctx` is enough to also figure out the `queue`).

Answer (score 6):

While it’s difficult to know exactly what the right solution to your problem is based on the code and context given, the error you’re seeing stems from the `HasJobQueue` typeclass, which is extremely general:

```
class HasJobQueue ctx queue where
  hasJobQueue :: JobQueue queue => ctx -> queue
```

From the typechecker’s point of view, `hasJobQueue` is a function from `a -> b`, plus a few constraints (but constraints do not generally affect type inference). This means that, in order to invoke `hasJobQueue`, both its input *and* its output must be entirely unambiguously specified by some other source of type information.

If this this confusing, consider a slightly different class that is nearly identical to the typechecker:

```
class Convert a b where
  convert :: a -> b
```

This typeclass is generally an antipattern (precisely because it makes type inference very hard), but it could theoretically be used to provide instances to convert between any two types. For example, one could write the following instance:

```
instance Convert Integer String where
  convert = show
```

…then use `convert` to convert an integer to a string:

```
ghci> convert (42 :: Integer) :: String
"42"
```

*However*, note that the following will **not** work:

```
ghci> convert (42 :: Integer)

<interactive>:26:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

The issue here is that GHC has no idea what `b` should be, so it can’t pick which `Convert` instance to use.

In your code, `hasJobQueue` is much the same, though the details are a little more complex. The issue arises in the following lines:

```
queue <- hasJobQueue <$> ask
enqueue (SaveDocument addr document) queue
```

In order to know which `HasJobQueue` instance to use, GHC needs to know the type of `queue`. Well, fortunately, GHC can infer types for bindings based on how they are *used*, so hopefully, `queue`’s type can be inferred. It is provided as the second argument to `enqueue`, so we can understand what’s going on by looking at the type of `enqueue`:

```
enqueue :: (JobQueue q, MonadIO m) => Command -> q -> m ()
```

And here we see the problem. The second argument of `enqueue` must have type `q`, which is *also* unconstrained, so GHC does not gain any additional information. Therefore, it can’t determine the type of `q`, and it doesn’t know which instance to use for *either* the call to `hasJobQueue` or the call to `enqueue`.

---

So how can you solve this? Well, one way would be to pick a particular type for `queue`, but based on your code, I’m betting that isn’t actually what you want. More likely, there is a *particular* type of queue associated with each particular `ctx`, so the return type of `hasJobQueue` should really be *implied* by its first argument. Fortunately, Haskell has a notion to encode this very thing, and that notion is *functional dependencies*.

Remember that I said at the beginning that constraints do not generally affect type inference? Functional dependencies change that. When you write a fundep, you state that the typechecker actually *can* gain information from a constraint because some of the type variables imply some of the others. In this case, you want `queue` to be implied by `ctx`, so you can change the definition of `HasJobQueue`:

```
class HasJobQueue ctx queue | ctx -> queue where
  hasJobQueue :: JobQueue queue => ctx -> queue
```

The `| ctx -> queue` syntax can be read as “`ctx` implies `queue`”.

Now, when you write `hasJobQueue <$> ask`, GHC already knows `ctx`, and it knows it can figure out `queue` from `ctx`. Therefore, the code is no longer ambiguous, and it can pick the correct instances.

---

Of course, nothing is for free. The functional dependency is nice, but what do we give up? Well, it means we promise that, for each `ctx`, there is *exactly* one `queue`, no more. Without the functional dependency, both of these instances can coexist:

```
instance HasJobQueue FooCtx MyQueueA
instance HasJobQueue FooCtx MyQueueB
```

These are totally legal, and GHC will pick the instance based on which type of queue is requested by the calling code. With the functional dependency, this is illegal, which makes sense—the whole point is that the second parameter must be implied by the first, and if two different options are possible, GHC can’t disambiguate by the first parameter alone.

In this sense, functional dependencies allow typeclass constraints to have “input” and “output” parameters. Sometimes, functional dependencies are called “type-level Prolog”, since they turn the constraint solver into a relational sublanguage. This is extremely powerful, and you can even write classes with bidirectional relations:

```
class Add a b c | a b -> c, a c -> b, b c -> a
```

Usually, though, most uses of functional dependencies involve cases like the one you ran into, where one structure semantically “has” an associated type. For example, one of the classic examples come from the mtl library, which use functional dependencies to represent reader context, writer state, etc.:

```
class MonadReader r m | m -> r
class MonadWriter w m | m -> w
class MonadState s m | m -> s
class MonadError e m | m -> e
```

This means they can be equivalently expressed in a slightly different way using associated types (part of the `TypeFamilies` extension)… but that is probably outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: This isn't too significant, but I'd read `->` here as "determines", rather than "implies".

Comment: Also, functional dependencies can always be replaced by equality constraints with type families, *unless* overlapping or incoherent instances are required.

Comment: Since `AsCloisterExc` is also a class, why is the functional dependency required with `HasJobQueue ctx queue, JobQueue queue` but not necessary with `MonadError exc m, AsCloisterExc exc`?

Comment: I added a link to the file that contains all of the data types so you can see it in action. That code currently compiles and runs, but I significantly changed techniques around the JobQueue.

Comment: @SavanniD'Gerinel That sounds like a separate question to me, so you should probably just open a new question, including a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. It is considered bad practice to modify your question a significant time after asking on SO, so you are encouraged to just ask new followup questions (though you can definitely link to this question to provide extra context).

Comment: Without that clarification, the question is not answered. But okay, I'll create a new one when I have the time.